# Change a column and then insert into another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

```
   insert into newTable    
        select one.col1 as first, two.col2 as second
        from thing1 as one inner join thing2 as two
        on SOMETHING
        where SOMETHING
```

I'm trying to insert into newTable the above. However, what I really want to do is

```
   insert into newTable    
        select one.col1 as first, two.col2 + 1 as second
        from thing1 as one inner join thing2 as two
        on SOMETHING
        where SOMETHING
```

meaning I want to change the second column (plus one) before inserting into the newTable.

How can I do this in Sqlite?

1). Create and name a temporary table, increment one (update the table), and then insert the result into the newTable? (How?)
Or
2). Do it directly / as concise as possible?

I tried:

```
 insert into newTable    
    update(
        select one.col1 as first, two.col2 as second
        from thing1 as one inner join thing2 as two
        on SOMETHING
        where SOMETHING
           )set second = second + 1
```

And that doesn't work. Can I do something similar?

Comment: Your insert query should work just fine with the `+ 1`.

Comment: Are you saying my second block of code should work?